# Adding new or overriding in an ArrayList with the same expression?

Tags: java, arraylist

So, as far as I've been able to find, you have two options when you want to add something to an arraylist:

- `.add(int index, E object)`
- `.set(int index, E object)`

If I understand correctly, `add()` only adds new entries, either to the end, or to the index specified, pushing everything on that index and behind it one spot backwards;
and `set()` only changes the value for an *already existing* entry.

Is there an expression available that overwrites the data at the given index if something is there, and creates a new entry if not?

Comment: No, unfortunately there is no such method available. You'll have to check before `set()` to see if an element already exist at that index or otherwise it will throw an exception.

Comment: Is there something similar to an arraylist available that does have this option? I'm not stuck on the arraylist, I'm more then happy to use anything else that has similar options (storing data with indexes).

Comment: Your question looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you really want to achieve? How are you panning to use such method/class? Maybe you are looking for `Map<Integer, ...>`?

Comment: If you are using a `HashMap` then using `put()` will put a new entry if the key does not already exist in the map or replace the existing value if key is already present in the map.

Comment: `LinkedHashMap` using the index as key?

Comment: Could there be gaps in the indices? E.g. 0, 1, 3, 8? If so it's definitely a Map that you want.

Comment: @Pshemo Apologies. Was just trying to clarify what I was looking for. I guess it's definitely a Map I'm looking for, thanks people.

Answer (score 0):

You can Override the `add` and `set` method of `ArrayList` if you want:

```
ArrayList<YourClass> list = new ArrayList<YourClass>() {
    @Override
    public void add(int index, YourClass element) {
        //Do what you want here
        //super.add(int index, YourClass element);
    }

    @Override
    public YourClass set(int index, YourClass element) {
        //Do what you want here
        //return super.set(int index, YourClass element);
    }
};
```